# error invoking "grub-mkrescue" - invocation fails

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, iso, grub-legacy

I am following along a tutorial on writing an OS and fail to create a bootable iso file. The tutorial uses grub-legacy but I use grub 2 since legacy is outdated.
The important part of the makefile looks like this:

```
mykernel.iso: mykernel.bin
    mkdir iso
    mkdir iso/boot
    mkdir iso/boot/grub
    cp mykernel.bin iso/boot/mykernel.bin
    echo 'set timeout=0'                      > iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'set default=0'                     >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo ''                                  >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'menuentry "My Operating System" {' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin'    >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  boot'                            >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '}'                                 >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    grub-mkrescue --output=mykernel.iso iso
    rm -rf iso
```

and the whole directory with its files looks like this: https://github.com/AlgorithMan-de/wyoos/tree/b440da72b6403d6cde728b6657e61aed8fd3c682

On my terminal I get the error:

```
(commands above grub-mkrescue --output=mykernel.iso iso)...

grub-mkrescue --output=mykernel.iso iso
grub-mkrescue: error: `mformat` invocation failed
.
make: *** [makefile:34: mykernel.iso] Error 1
```

I have xorriso version 1.5.4 (I read that it is needed) but not grub-legacy
as it is said to be required in the tutorial because its outdated.
Does anyone have an idea what I need to do to boot from this iso image? Thanks!
The only thing I found on google was this:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=219955
and I executed "sudo apt install pacman -S mtools" but the error message remains the same.

Comment: The failing mformat run is most probably the one at the end of this comment.
(With some other text instead of XXXXXX so that it points to an already 
existing directory. See
https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/util/grub-mkrescue.c#n854 ):
mformat -C -f 2880 -L 16 -i /tmp/XXXXXX/efi.img ::

Answer (score 0):

In case you still have no usable program mformat installed:

Possibly you took the proposal for Archlinux too literally.
"pacman" is their package manager. Try:

```
sudo apt install mtools
```

Comment: yes you are right, it works now. many thanks!!